# Battery heating up instead of a coil in a simple heat circuit

Tags: heat

I am making a simple heat circuit using 9v battery and a coil made up of AWG 18-gauge copper wire (electrical engineering newbie working on a fun project). I followed these steps http://www.ehow.com/how_10022230_make-heat-circuit.html but what happens is battery heats up instead of a coil. Looks like battery is shorting. Can anyone suggest how can I troubleshoot the problem? I kept the circuit connected for about 2 minutes but after that coil didn't heat up at all but battery was noticeably hot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm not surprised in the slightest.

"about 4 inches of bare AWG 18-gauge wire" would have a resistance of around 2mΩ and the current carrying capacity of it for chassis wiring is in the order of 16A.

So yes, the battery was short circuited.  It would be trying to draw in the order of 4500A from the battery.

The whole notion of doing that is just daft.  Whoever wrote that article doesn't have a clue.

There is a special form of wire, called *nichrome* (short for Nickel-Chromium) which is a resistive wire. It's used for creating heating elements, and for using high power potentiometers (known as a *rheostat*), that would give far superior results.

Comment: Don't be daft LOL- that's 4" in length of coils not a straight 4" of uncoiled wire ;) - it's still a daft experiment and the website should be totally ridiculed. It could cause a fire and it could burn someone.

Comment: The way it reads to me says it's just 4 inches of wire: "Wind about 4 inches of bare AWG 18-gauge wire loosely around a pencil." not "Wide bare AWG 18-gauge wire loosely around a pencil until it covers about 4 inches of the pencil."...

Comment: 4 inches of coiled 18g would only be a few feet at best. 1mm diameter wire, 4 inches (101mm) in height, 25mm in pencil circumference, i see like 2 to 3 feet at most coil calculators. Negligible resistance, still a dead short across a 9V battery.

Comment: Thanks Majenko. Whatever you said makes perfect sense. If I use nichrome wire for coil while keeping other things intact, will it create battery powered heat circuit? I want to generate somewhat around 100 degree celsius using 9v battery.

Comment: Not sure 100° is going to be that good using a little PP3, but I did once make some electrically heated gloves using nichrome.

Answer (score 0):

To most effectively heat your coil, you'll [want to match its impedance to the battery's.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching#Power_transfer) A Duracell 9V lithium battery has an impedance of [.775 ohms](http://ww2.duracell.com/media/en-US/pdf/gtcl/Product_Data_Sheet/NA_DATASHEETS/DL1604-9V%20Ultra%20Lithium%20Dioxide.pdf). 18 gauge copper wire has a resistance of [.006385 ohms per foot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge). So, you'll need 121 feet of that 18 gauge wire to make an effective heater. Or, you could use a much thinner wire -- if you used 38 gauge wire instead you'd only need 1.2 feet